# Destination not defined error on grunt replace

Tags: javascript, replace, npm, gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt replace to change the names of files and add a random number to the file to prevent caching of images, css and js files.

So I am running the following code

```js
module.exports = function replace(grunt) {

  var randomVersion = ((new Date()).valueOf().toString()) + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1).toString());
  var replace = {

      options: {
        variables: {
          'randomVersion': randomVersion
        },
        overwrite: true
      },
      files: [{
        src: './target/dist/index.html',
        dest: './target/dist/index.' + randomVersion + '.html'
      }]
  };

  console.log(randomVersion);

  grunt.config.set('replace', replace);
};
```

but all I get back is a "Destination is not defined

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely certain about what your code is trying to achieve, but I will proceed to answer according to my understanding.

First, are you trying to use the [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outatime/grunt-replace) library? If so, I think this is incorrect. This library is for replacing values *within the contents* of source files, and *not* the file paths themselves.

It looks to me that what you want to do is to copy your source index.html file to a file path with a unique identifier in it. You may be trying to wrap this in a custom task, but doing so is not necessary.

The following is a sample Gruntfile.js of how I would achieve this task. Note that this solution requires the installation of the [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) and [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) libraries.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        clean: {
            dist: ['./target/dist/index.*.html']
        },

        copy: {
            dist: {
                src: './target/src/index.html',
                dest: './target/dist/index.<%= Date.now() %>.html'       
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'copy']);

};
```

There are a few things about this solution that are worth pointing out:

- The index.html file *is not* in the /dist folder because it is not
  intended for distribution, but is, rather, a source.
- Before creating new versions of index.*.html, we will delete any
  existing versions in the /dist folder so that we don't have an
  accumulation of each version.
- Instead of using a "random" number for our versions, we will use a
  timestamp. This is helpful because each version will have a greater
  number than the one before it.